# How to remove values that do not satisfy the condition?

Tags: r, datetime, comparison

I have a dataset that contains several date-time variables. I wanted to delete the values in the variables that do not satisfy a condition. For example, I have date_time, date_time1, date_time2 (in POSIXct format). If date_time1 < date_time < date_time2, then delete this row.
This is the mock data frame:

```
    final <- data.frame (id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                    date_time = c('2022-07-01 12:01:00', '2022-07-01 12:02:00', '2022-07-01 12:03:00', '2022-07-01 12:04:00', '2022-07-01 12:05:00', '2022-07-01 12:06:00', '2022-07-01 12:07:00', '2022-07-01 12:08:00'),
                    date_time1 = c('2022-07-01 12:04:00', '2022-07-01 12:04:00', '2022-07-01 12:04:00', '2022-07-01 12:04:00', '2022-07-01 12:04:00', '2022-07-01 12:04:00', '2022-07-01 12:04:00', '2022-07-01 12:04:00'),
                    date_time2 = c('2022-07-01 12:07:00', '2022-07-01 12:07:00', '2022-07-01 12:07:00', '2022-07-01 12:07:00', '2022-07-01 12:07:00', '2022-07-01 12:07:00', '2022-07-01 12:07:00', '2022-07-01 12:07:00'))
```

The data frame should look like

```
id  date_time             date_time1            date_time2

1  2022-07-01 12:01:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
2  2022-07-01 12:02:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
3  2022-07-01 12:03:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
4  2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
5  2022-07-01 12:05:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
6  2022-07-01 12:06:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
7  2022-07-01 12:07:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
8  2022-07-01 12:08:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
```

My code is:

```
final$delete <- ifelse((final$date_time > final$date_time1 
                              & final$date_time < final$date_time2), 'delete', 'keep')
final[with(final, !(delete=='delete')),]
```

So what I want after the condition
date_time1 < date_time < date_time2

```
id date_time             date_time1            date_time2
1  2022-07-01 12:01:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
2  2022-07-01 12:02:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
3  2022-07-01 12:03:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
4  2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
7  2022-07-01 12:07:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
8  2022-07-01 12:08:00   2022-07-01 12:04:00   2022-07-01 12:07:00
```

id 5 and id 6 should be removed.

However, after I used my code, the dataset remained the same. I do not know why. Thank you if you can help.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of data, but rather use code blocks, as suggested in the edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` with a one-liner, after we convert the dates to proper datetime objects.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

final |> 
    mutate(across(matches('date_time'), as_datetime)) |> 
    filter(!(date_time > date_time1 & date_time < date_time2)) 

  id           date_time          date_time1          date_time2
1  1 2022-07-01 12:01:00 2022-07-01 12:04:00 2022-07-01 12:07:00
2  2 2022-07-01 12:02:00 2022-07-01 12:04:00 2022-07-01 12:07:00
3  3 2022-07-01 12:03:00 2022-07-01 12:04:00 2022-07-01 12:07:00
4  4 2022-07-01 12:04:00 2022-07-01 12:04:00 2022-07-01 12:07:00
5  7 2022-07-01 12:07:00 2022-07-01 12:04:00 2022-07-01 12:07:00
6  8 2022-07-01 12:08:00 2022-07-01 12:04:00 2022-07-01 12:07:00
```

Comment: It still do not work in the real dataset. No rows were filtered. I think the problem is the date-time format.

Comment: We may have to convert to proper datetime columns before the operation, se the updated answer

Comment: The system said I need to have 15 reputation to vote...

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure to overwrite `final` as the last step:

```
final <- final[with(final, !(delete=='delete')),]
```

Comment: The problem is in the previous step.

Comment: This answer is the best one.  The other answer probably also works, but it is unnecessarily complicated.